# Pandas list down unique values in column and assign it to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have following table:

[image]

I want to create new data frame or column in same data frame where unique values are listed. e.g.

[image]

I used following code:

```
data.groupby('EMAIL')['Classification'].transform('nunique')
```

But it is giving me number of unique values (for CLASSIFICATION, it is 2),
However I want to note down value in list format. So that at the end i will remove duplicate rows and put single row for each unique email id. Please advise on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance use `set` for unique values and pass to lambda function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html), order should be different like original:

```
df = data.groupby('EMAIL').agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x))).reset_index()
```

For same order like original use dictionary trick:

```
f = ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()) 
df = data.groupby('EMAIL').agg(f).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.groupby(as_index=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`df.groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
data.groupby('EMAIL',as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))
```